# Print complete WebKitWebView (not only visible part) into PDF with gtk3 and cairo

Tags: pdf, webkit, cairo, gtk3, scrolledwindow

I want to save a webpage using webkit, gtk3 and cairo into a pdf.

---

What works: The visible part (visible in window) gets correctly printed into the pdf

---

What doesn't work, but should work: The invisible part (the part when you scroll down) should be printed into that pdf, too. Any ideas?

---

That's my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
#include <cairo-pdf.h>


static void save_as_pdf (GtkWidget *widget, const char *filename) 
{
        GtkAllocation allocation;

        printf("Saving PDF to file %s\n", filename);
        gtk_widget_get_allocation(GTK_WIDGET(widget), &allocation);
        printf("height: %d width: %d\n", allocation.height, allocation.width);
        cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_pdf_surface_create( filename, allocation.width, allocation.height);

        cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
        gtk_widget_draw(widget, cr);
        cairo_destroy(cr);
        cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

}


static void notifyProgressCb(WebKitWebView* webView, GParamSpec* pspec, GtkWidget* window)
{
        float progress = webkit_web_view_get_progress(webView);
        printf("\x1b[1G\t\x1b[1G%f", progress * 100); fflush(stdout);

        if (progress == 1.0)
                save_as_pdf(window, "test.pdf");

}

int main (int   argc, char *argv[])
{
        GtkWidget *window;
        WebKitWebView *webView;

        gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1024, 768);

        webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());

        gtk_container_set_resize_mode(GTK_CONTAINER(webView), GTK_RESIZE_PARENT);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), GTK_WIDGET(webView));

        g_signal_connect(webView, "notify::progress", G_CALLBACK(notifyProgressCb), webView);


        webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, "http://www.heise.de");


        g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        gtk_widget_show_all (window);

        gtk_main();

        return 0;
}
```

compile with:

> gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs --cflags webkitgtk-3.0` yourfile.c

Comment: Your code works fine here on Fedora 19 with webkitgtk 2.0.3, the whole page gets saved. "Saving PDF to file test.pdf, height: 5781 width: 1225." http://people.gnome.org/~klember/test.pdf

Comment: @kalev hmm, interesting; does the opened window show the complete website (i.e. you don't have to scroll)? Perhaps you just have a bigger screen and the complete website fits into the window.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the cairo_create() method only draws the part of the WebView widget, which is visible inside the window. In this case, I would completely circumvent the WebkitGtk objects and include some code which downloads the web page, renders it and saves the output into a PDF file; HTML2PDF, for instance. It may be a dirty low-level approach, but it's more robust and easier to implement.

Comment: I don't think it's easier to create a HTML renderer ;) - and what about javascript and css?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [this](https://github.com/potyl/Webkit/blob/master/screenshot.pl):

**Save a page as a PDF:**

```
screenshot.pl --output cpan.pdf http://search.cpan.org/
```